# Can Bootstrap push-pull grid push a div to a new different row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'll try and explain this challenge... I have three divs, ordered for mobile first in a bootstrap WordPress theme.

[1] NAV

[2] CONTENT

[3] SIDEBAR

This code, works fine:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><p>NAV</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-right" ><p>MAIN CONTENT : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et diam et erat imperdiet scelerisque ac a leo. Etiam eu ultrices tortor, a aliquet felis. Morbi sit amet placerat mi. Nulla feugiat id sem non faucibus. Nunc tortor turpis, faucibus non nisi sit amet, bibendum tincidunt arcu. Duis id risus porttitor, porttitor massa eget, elementum ligula. Proin ullamcorper, lacus quis porta luctus, dolor enim hendrerit massa, varius gravida est ipsum quis elit. Quisque ex felis, commodo a placerat non, egestas eu turpis. Praesent sit amet lobortis tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porta nibh non erat suscipit, et rhoncus mauris finibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque quam mauris, sagittis ut orci eget, tempor sollicitudin nunc. Mauris consequat ex quis dolor viverra, ac dictum eros dapibus.</p></div>

        <div class="col-md-4  col-md-pull"><p>SIDEBAR</p></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

However, on full desktop view, the sidebar displays after the main content finishes, and I need it to display directly beneath the left hand side nav - i.e.

[1 ------ NAV -------] [2------------------CONTENT -----------------]

[3 ----SIDEBAR----] [2------------CONTENT CONTINUED-----]

------------------------- [2------------CONTENT CONTINUED-----]

Instead, it displays like this.

[1 ------ NAV -------] [2------------------CONTENT -----------------]

________________[2------------CONTENT CONTINUED-----]

________________[2------------CONTENT CONTINUED-----]

[3 ----SIDEBAR----]

I don't usually do advanced CSS like this, and have been let down by my contractor, if anybody could help, and at least let me know if this is possible or not that would be much appreciated.

Also this is my first post here, so apologies if this isn't in standard format etc.

Regards
Simon

Comment: Have you tried to put the SIDEBAR code in a DIV that exists in the same col-md-4 as the NAV? Second suggestion would be to create a nested table where the NAV is.

Comment: Thanks crazymatt - first solution works on desktop, but them mobile order is wrong:


[1] NAV

[3] SIDEBAR

[2] CONTENT


...  would rather avoid tables but will have a go at that option - thanks

Comment: Ahh i see what you are saying. Its definitely possible but would be pretty involved to accomplish. Time to hire another contractor?